# What Azure Active Directory editions support OpenID Connect (OIDC)?

Tags: azure-active-directory

We currently have Azure Active Directory O365 edition, but need to know what editions support Open ID Connect (OIDC). I have been reviewing documentation and pricing matrixes but cannot tell for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, **All**.

Even the free AAD edition supports OIDC.

No matter which edition your O365 is, you have the associated AAD tenant. So you can definitely use [OIDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc) to configure login authentication for your users.